# Unit testing enable and disable method on reactive forms

Tags: angular, forms, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, angular-reactive-forms

Hi I am writing tests for reactive form in angular and I am having hard time testing this part of the code

```
setForm(): void {
    const firstName = this.form.get('firstName');
    const lastName = this.form.get('lastName');

    lastName.disable();
    lastName.clearValidators();
    lastName.setValue('');

    firstName.enable();
    firstName.setValidators([Validators.required]);
}
```

This is a part of FormService file where I set the reactive form controls, validation and etc.
Is there a way to test this?

Answer (score 0):

When you're writing tests for a public API method, you usually need to ask yourself "what should the result be after this method has been executed?". In your case, after `setForm()` is executed the `firstName` control should be enabled and marked as required and the `lastName` control should be disabled and with no value. Your test would look like this:

```js
  it('should enable the firstName control and disable the lastName control when setForm() is called', () => {
    const firstName = component.form.get('firstName');
    const lastName = component.form.get('lastName');
    component.setForm();
    expect(firstName.enabled).toBe(true);
    expect(firstName.hasValidator(Validators.required)).toBe(true);
    expect(lastName.disabled).toBe(true);
    expect(lastName.value).toBeFalsy();
  });
```